# mongodb query - Upsert a value and then get the incremented value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The following query updated the collection and increments the field `count`. I want to send the updated `count` as a response without making another api call.

The variable `usage` does not project the values.

```
handler.put(async (req, res) => {
  console.log("in backend api to update geo count")
  await req.db.collection('analytics').updateOne(
    {
    _id: getDateMonYear(new Date(), "mmddyyyy"),
    type: "Geo",
    },
    {
      $inc: { "count": 1},
    },
    {upsert: true},
    
  );
  res.status(200).send({usage});
});
```

Expected result sent back as json response:

```
{
    "_id": "Sept292022",
    "type": "Geo",
    "count": 162
}
```

Edit, I made it work by hitting the collection again like below but is there a way to just return in the update above?

```
  const usage = await req.db.collection('analytics')
  .findOne(
    {
      _id: getDateMonYear(new Date(), "mmddyyyy"),
    }
  );
  res.json({status:200, usage});
});
```

Comment: findAmdModify()?

Comment: I am able to find a modify. The collection is updated correctly. The question is about how to send the result as a json object back as `res` in the expected result format

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear and also had a typo. I was trying to ask if [the findAndModify() operation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/), rather than updateOne() that you are currently using, is what you need

Comment: Thanks but I am on version 4.x. findAndModify is only available in version 5. Regardless, I am already able to find and update but looking to send the resulting row as a json object back to client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`{returnNewDocument: true}`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) in the options, to get the updated document in the response:

```
await req.db.collection('analytics').updateOne(
    {
    _id: getDateMonYear(new Date(), "mmddyyyy"),
    type: "Geo",
    },
    {
      $inc: { "count": 1},
    },
    {upsert: true, returnNewDocument: true}
  );
```

Comment: Confirmed this works as expected!

Comment: AFAICT, `returnNewDocument` seems to be a parameter specific to the MongoDB shell implementation of the `findOneAndModify()` function. Can you help me understand why/how this is working for the `updateOne()` command in the node driver? A link to those specific docs would be helpful.  I can only find reference to [a `returnDocument` parameter](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.10/interfaces/FindOneAndUpdateOptions.html#returnDocument) for the `FindOneAndUpdateOptions` interface in the driver.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the edits it looks like things are moving in the right direction. I'm a bit confused by the comments, so perhaps this answer will help clarify things.

My understanding of your current server code is that it looks like the following now:

```
handler.put(async (req, res) => {
  console.log("in backend api to update geo count")
  await req.db.collection('analytics').updateOne(
    {
    _id: getDateMonYear(new Date(), "mmddyyyy"),
    type: "Geo",
    },
    {
      $inc: { "count": 1},
    },
    {upsert: true},
    
  );
  const usage = await req.db.collection('analytics')
  .findOne(
    {
      _id: getDateMonYear(new Date(), "mmddyyyy"),
    }
  );
  res.status(200).send({usage});
});
```

Was the problem originally that the `usage` object that the client was receiving was not the actual document that was updated?

If both of these things are correct, then using `findAndModify()` is the correct approach here. The problem with the original code is that the [output of `updateOne()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#returns) is a summary of the operation as opposed to the document itself. On the other hand, [the `findAndModify()` operation returns the document that was modified](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#return-data) (either before or after).  Also, this operation has been around for many years, introduced long before `4.4`.

So I think your code should look something like the following to achieve your desired result:

```
handler.put(async (req, res) => {
  console.log("in backend api to update geo count")
  const usage = await req.db.collection('analytics').findAndModify({
    query: {
    _id: getDateMonYear(new Date(), "mmddyyyy"),
    type: "Geo",
    },
    update: {
      $inc: { "count": 1},
    },
    upsert: true,
  });
  res.status(200).send({usage});
});
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, it would also be helpful to confirm what driver and driver version you are using.

Comment: I am getting 500 response. Also seems like findAndModify is deprecated. I use 4.4.1. `DeprecationWarning: collection.findAndModify is deprecated. Use findOneAndUpdate, findOneAndReplace or findOneAndDelete instead`

Comment: I upvoted your answer for the attempt but the correct answer the one that I accepted above - for anyone reading this in future.

Comment: Thanks. Just to connect a few dots, looks like `findAndModify()` has now been replaced by the more specific helpers like `findOneAndUpdate()`. You can see that @nimrod serok's link goes to the `findOneAndUpdate()` page for the MongoDB shell where the `returnNewDocument` parameter exists. I can't actually find a reference to that parameter for the node driver itself, [seems to be returnDocument instead](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.10/interfaces/FindOneAndUpdateOptions.html#returnDocument).  Similar comment [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8261)